# "Bet" in the beginning of the sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-patterns, sentence-starts, conversational-deletion

Bet it was a quick death, though. In this sentence, there is no noun before "Bet". Does it refer to "you" or "I"?

Answer (score 3):

It refers to "I", always.

This omission is a practice you find with other verbs, in particular "tell" in the past tense; it is informal.

- Told you they wouldn't come. ([ref.](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-modal-would.php))

Comment: [***You betchya**!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22you+betchya%22) :)